# Best possible ways to move the data from On-prem SQL Server to Cloud SQL instance with very minimal downtime

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-sql

I have a requirement to move around 30 DB's from On-prem SQL Server to google Cloud SQL instance with very minimal downtime.

I thought of doing Logshipping/High avaialbility but Gcloud SQL is not supporting sysadmin role to add secondary instance in On-prem SQL Server.

Please let me know if there are any other ways to do this

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is with a backup and a restore, but you're going to have downtime in that regard. Quite a lot of it really.

The one way you can do this is through replication. No other facility is likely to help you move to Google Cloud SQL without downtime. [Here's an example of how to set it up.](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-data-from-sql-server-to-cloud-sql-for-sql-server)

Comment: In the given link, they are using compute engine from the Google cloud and setting up one sql server inside that. Our requirement is bit different like we have to setup similar kind of replica from On-premise environment to CloudSQL

Comment: Networking will be different. Other than that the process should be the same.

Comment: it won't work from on-prem to CloudSQL as replication needed one Sysadmin role user and currently cloudsql is not supporting any sysadmin roles

Comment: Depending on data changes: not a lot. Full backup, move up, then apply log backups until current. YOu SHOULD be able to handle downtime down to a couple of hours, which you can put on a dea time.

Answer (score 0):

[This document](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-data-between-sql-server-2008-and-cloud-sql-for-sql-server-using-backup-files) applies exactly to your case and it's the best way to do it, basically the steps are:

1. [Enable](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=sqladmin,storage_component&_ga=2.119632968.1931733241.1598285812-1125568183.1588193145&_gac=1.15910786.1597776183.EAIaIQobChMI6ryejLSl6wIVg8DACh0BTAd2EAAYASAAEgIjIfD_BwE) the Cloud Storage and Cloud SQL APIs
2. [Create](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-data-between-sql-server-2008-and-cloud-sql-for-sql-server-using-backup-files#creating_the_cloud_sql_instance_and_cloud_storage_bucket) the SQL instance and Cloud Storage bucket (where you will deposit the backup created from your On-prem DB)
3. [Create](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-data-between-sql-server-2008-and-cloud-sql-for-sql-server-using-backup-files#backing_up_your_database) a backup from your On-prem DB, this steps depends on your version but I think that the step detailed gives you and idea, and then upload it into the just created bucket
4. [Import](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-data-between-sql-server-2008-and-cloud-sql-for-sql-server-using-backup-files#importing_the_backup_file_to_cloud_sql) the backup created into Google Cloud SQL from your Storage bucket

The [last](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-data-between-sql-server-2008-and-cloud-sql-for-sql-server-using-backup-files#validating_the_data_import) step performed in the guide is just to validate recent imported data by connecting to the instance and execute a query.
For SQL Server 2017 [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-data-between-sql-server-2017-and-cloud-sql-for-sql-server-using-backup-files) is the exact same guide but for that specific version.

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, thanks for the information and I wanted to reiterate the requirement here.. We have few TB's of data in our servers and we wanted to migrate that data(taking backup and copying that to GCloud storage bucket will be an expensive task and its gonna take lot of time both interms taking the backup and transfering the.Bak files to Gcloudstroage)

Comment: There's a way to do it by external replication but it only applies to [MySQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/replication-from-external), it's not available to Cloud SQL possibly because it's a [relative new](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/release-notes#February_19_2020) product on GCP.

Regarding the transfer you could possible apply to [Cloud Data Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/products/data-transfer) which will allow you to move TBs of  information into Cloud Storage and then restore your databases as needed from any bucket.